# Close button doesn't work on Reject Suggested Edit popup

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

On page for reviewing suggested edits when click on <kbd>Reject</kbd> button popup is opened. This popup has close button <kbd>X</kbd>, but this button doesn't work. Popup can be close by clicking outside of it and with <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, and this works fine. I'm using Firefox 19.0.

Comment: I can reproduce this. (Also on Firefox 19, Mac OS X).

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome, Win7. ESC does close the window.

Comment: Have same prob in Chrome